# How to make a custom adapter to retrieve from firebase database and sort on the client side and then populate adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I've lat and lng stored in the firebase database. Now I want to retrieve these and then calculate the distance between my current location and those points and then sort them in increasing order of distance in the adapter

I am able to retrieve the lat and lng and calculate distance and populate the firebase recyclerview adapter. But in this adapter, the items are not sorted according to the distance. I want to sort them according to the distance calculated after retrieving the item.

Code in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter inside onBindViewHolder

```
lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
lat1 = Double.parseDouble(model.getMylat());
lng1 = Double.parseDouble(model.getMylng());
loadLocationForThisUser(lat, lng, lat1, lng1);
holder.txt_distance.setText(distance);
```

And code to calculate the distance

```
private void loadLocationForThisUser(Double lat, Double lng, Double lat1, Double lng1) {


    //Create location from user coordinates
    currentUser1 = new Location("");
    currentUser1.setLatitude(lat);
    currentUser1.setLongitude(lng);

    //Create location from friend coordinates
    friend1 = new Location("");
    friend1.setLatitude(lat1);
    friend1.setLongitude(lng1);


    distanceNumeric = (int) (currentUser1.distanceTo(friend1)/1000);
    Log.i("distanceNumeric", String.valueOf(distanceNumeric));

    distance = (new 
DecimalFormat("#.#").format((currentUser1.distanceTo(friend1)) / 1000)+ " 
kms");
}
```

Currently, the output is items being populated without any order of sorting based on the distance calculated. I'm expecting the adapter to be populated with items in increasing order of distance that has been calculated.

Comment: This sounds like a follow up to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071765/is-there-a-way-to-sort-the-firebaserecyclerview-after-i-calculate-value-after-re). Did you try the `getItem` trick I mentioned there?

Comment: I tried the `getItem` but couldn't figure out how to fit it into my problem, like how would I sort the distances in increasing order with the `getItem` method?

Comment: If you think your distance calculation is going wrong, show the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you think your adapter is wrong, show the minimal code to reproduce *that* problem. It's much more likely that someone can and will help if you reduce the scope of your problem. I **highly** recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for hints on how to do that.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my previous question to make it clear where I'm facing the problem.